# Why didn’t the breaker trip when an outlet shorted against a metal box?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

House flooded and water mitigation crew was removing drywall and apparently dislodged an outlet inside a metal junction box. I noticed sometime later that the hot side had made contact with the metal box causing damage to both the box and the terminals and a little bit of wire. (See pic). I’m lucky this didn’t get worse and cause a fire. Why didn’t the breaker trip?

[image]

Subpanel:
[image: The subpanel]

Comment: Picture of your panel will be most helpful.  A few panels are defective and basically have a remove yesterday recommendation.

Comment: This is a very good example of the use of metal boxes. Melting and burning plastic boxes are not a good thing.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact but if it were a plastic box, the contacts would not have shorted across the box side wall right? What am I missing (I'm an untrained DIYer)?

Comment: The water would have still filled the box and caused a partial short. Distilled water hardly conducts at all. Dirty water (rain, flood, etc.) does conduct some - enough to kill (which is why we have GFCI). No way to know for sure whether there would be more damage (because plastic doesn't protect like metal) or less damage (because less chance for water to bridge screws than to bridge from a screw to the metal box) but I'd prefer the metal box.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Read the question. The short happened when somebody physically impacted the receptacle while removing drywall, not due to water filling the box.

Comment: @nobody Aha. I thought it was initially water damage (since that's why the drywall was being removed, etc.). It looks awfully bad for a "bang into the box" type of short, and *that* type of short (unlike water damage) really should be full short = breaker trip.

Comment: @nobody "apparently dislodged" is not a certainty that *what seems apparent is what happened.* It flooded, various things including removal of drywall happened without it being noticed, and then it was noticed. Anything past that and the arc damage is speculation.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not full hard contact. Breaker presumably was not an AFCI (arc-fault) which should have tripped on the arc. *In this particular case a GFCI should also have tripped with an arc to ground causing imbalanced current in hot and neutral.*

Regular breaker won't trip if the arc current is not over its rating, and won't trip FAST unless the arc current is WELL over its rating. So a 2.4 KW arc on a 20A circuit or a 1.8 KW arc on a 15 A circuit (120V) will burn until it self-extinguishes (from burning/melting the contact points back so far the arc can't maintain itself.) For typical trip curves, it could start twice as powerful for a minute or more without tripping.

So, graphic evidence of why AFCIs are now required in more places. And if they are not required in your place yet, or because you're grandfathered, reasons to consider adding them anyway.

The arc when my oven element blew was impressive, but evidently well below the 12KW of the 50A 240V breaker supplying the range.

*There is the edge-case @crip659 mentions of certain makes/models of mostly 40+ year old breakers that don't trip, but I'd guess that's not the case here or there would (probably) be **more** damage evident.*

Comment: The panel is 22 years old. Was inspected when I bought the house last year. No mention of recall at that point. Regular breaker on this circuit not arc or ground protected. My question is should have an electrician look at this? Or good to replace once I trim back the melted wire. I don’t think this would happen again if mounted in the box and not disturbed. But that looks like pretty significant contact with the damage created. Looks like home welding. So should I have the breaker checked??

Comment: You could show and/or tell us what the panel and breaker are, but as far as I know anything 22 years young is not among the flambé your house crowd. It's clearly arc damage. The nature of arc damage is that it does not need hard contact, because the circuit is completed and maintained by plasma. Since the plasma has more resistance than a hard contact, it can limit the current. You may well not have enough un-heat-damaged wire to trim back to without replacing a section of cable, which should be easy to do with the drywall off. You'll also want to replace that mud ring.

Comment: As already mentioned in the answer, you *may* wish to upgrade to AFCI/GFCI protection. That need not be a breaker, if installed via metallic conduit from the panel for AFCI, or as the first receptacle for GFCI.

Comment: I added a pic of the sub panel feeding this circuit. I didn't take the cover off obviously...

Comment: A "defective in the won't trip manner" Square-D QO is unlikely in the extreme. I think it's a QO rather than a Homeline, (can't quite read it, not sharp enough, but it looks familiar and I have QOs, rather looking than slightly off) though neither are prone to burning your house down, the QOs are the better of the two for other reasons.

Comment: Those are definitely QOs. Homeline is the same length/height but much wider.

Comment: Legitimate QOs are great, but as the other answer points out, third parties have produced counterfeits, which have been recalled for being counterfeit and possibly failing to trip on overload.

Answer (score 1):

How far away was this outlet from the panel, what size wire (appears to be romex), what size breaker for that circuit?  It may have been a perfect storm where the length of wire was sufficiently long to have a high enough resistance that the breaker did not instantly trip.

Standard thermal-magnetic breakers will trip "instantly" for short circuits (ie 10x rated) or slowly (ie 17A on a 15A breaker) which could take minutes or even hours. If the length of the wire was long enough the short circuit current might not be high enough to instantly trip the breaker.  QO breakers in my experience are on the sensitive side so that's a little odd  There was an issue with counterfeit QO breakers but I don't think the dates line up with the age of your house. https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2007/north-american-breaker-co-recalls-counterfeit-circuit-breakers-due-to-fire-hazard

Comment: Counterfeit breakers seems like a definite possibility. The dates aren't quite right but the embossed-only amp rating (instead of painted white on a legitimate breaker) is concerning.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that nowhere in the code is an outlet required to have a low enough resistance for the estimated short circuit current to be more than 10x the circuit rating.

Answer (score 0):

In Minnesota,  if the panel was flooded, you're required to replace it and the breakers as they are no longer reliable. Insurance companies also require their replacement.

Comment: The problem, and presumably the flooding, was with a receptacle in a box in the wall, not with the main panel.

Comment: While possibly true, this does not answer the question and may get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The arcing probably didn't create a sustained current to trip immediately. Looking at a circuit breaker inverse time curve might shed some light. A sustained current 5x the rated current can take 10 seconds to trip.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simple and complicated at the same time. I have been doing electrical work for 28 yrs.  I have spent nearly 25 of those years in the service side of electrical for residential, commercial, and industrial facillities.
THERE ARE ALOT A VARIABLES HERE TO BE CONSIDERED. Some great points have already been  discussed. Short answer, hire a reputable COMPETENT electrician. I personally receive phone calls from electricians asking me questions about this very same thing as they are trying to moonlight and make an extra buck.
Let's dive in.
1st, panel type does have to do with the non trip situation. I have worked with gear that you can literally weld with and never trip a breaker at all, and then I have worked with gear ( non gfci or afci ) that would trip super duper fast and it all be from the same panel type and breaker type.
2. Length from panel. When dealing with electricity it is very important to not exceed a total length of run from the power source that will add a significant enough voltage drop that the breaker will not recognize a short due to voltage spike not being high enough to register a problem. ( here is food for thought, why does a breaker not trip or fuse blow for heat strip or light bulb? It's a dead short!!!! )
3. Adequate bonding and grounding. Not just a 3 foot piece of ground rod rod driven will work . Especially if there is a 10 guage wire running to it for a 200 amp panel ( saw worse then that ). Neutrals and grounds separated or joined properly in the correct locations. Length of ground or neutral coming back to panel sized correctly.
4. And the list can go on. Including number of taps installed along the path.

I know this does not exactly answer the question. For me personally, I would have to be there to see in order to tell you exactly what happened or why it happened.
Another example of competency. I literally one night received a call at around 11 pm. An electrician I know was working on a large industrial fan that kept an area cool for its furry residents at a facility. He said he has been there for about 4 hours and cannot figure out why the fan quit working for this customer. He said he even swapped the motor out for the fan with a known good motor. I asked him if he checked power to the outlet? Yes. Ok, did you check power on the cord at the point it enters motor? Yes. Did you check power to the cord when it enters into the motor with the plug plugged into the outlet? His reply was. I'm not an idiot!!! Then a big pause and a laugh. He said well, I still don't have power. Oh, ok. I replied, then Change the cord. That is you issue. Goodnight!!.
Not all electricians are equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the ground wire going from your box back to the panel has failed – opening up inside the sheathing to save the breaker. You will want to check this before putting drywall back on.

My fifty year old house has a lot of original wiring with 14/2 nonmetallic sheathing in paper and tar. After removing a run down a humid wall to a basement outlet during renovation, I was taking the wire apart to use it for other things like hanging outdoor Christmas lights. In the process I discovered that the smaller ground wire was greatly thinned by corrosion.